# VB.net Erasing part of an array only

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need to find a way to erase part of a structure array but not wipe the whole thing. So example.

```
Structure PersonelList
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Age As Integer
End Structure

Dim Personel(4, 6000) As PersonelList
```

I would like to only erase say the 2nd index so Personel(2,x). I know how to wipe the whole thing such as.

```
Array.Clear(Personel, 0, 6000)
```

or

```
Erase Personel
```

But I have no idea how I can erase that one list without doing a for loop which I desperately want to avoid for processing time.

Comment: Use a jagged array or an array of List(Of PersonelList).

Comment: Do you have to use an array?  List(Of PersonelList) makes add/removing from collections much easier.  If you do have to use an array, what happens if you remove say the second element?  everything after one index up and re-dim the array or leave an empty element?

Comment: I dont need to I guess its just very easy to read. It has actually around 10 other types such as location etc. I have other lists so its taking time to wipe so if I was able to just empty as above it would dramatically speed up the time. I can look into  List(Of PersonelList)

Comment: Can you confirm you want a 2 dimensional array (or whatever), ie, 4 x 6,000 = 24,000 entries?

Comment: Yes this is correct within the structure as provided.